# Firebase: Cannot add user entry (`set` permission denied)

Tags: firebase, permission-denied, firebase-security

I want to ensure that a new user can be created (from the client), but only an authenticated user can read or write an existing object.

I have a simple rule set:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
              ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",
              ".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling `createUser` and then in the callback I'm trying to add an entry to my own `users` object:

```
const usersRef = ref.child('users');

const userEntry = {
    [userData.uid]: {
        created: new Date().getTime()
    }
};

usersRef.set(userEntry)
```

I would have thought that even though the user is not yet logged in, they should have write permission because of `!data.exists()`. Yet I am getting a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error.

If I set `".write": true` on the `users` level then it will cascade (and override?) my inner rules won't it?

**Edit:**

This fails even with:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "If I set ".write": true on the users level then it will cascade (and override?) my inner rules won't it?" Yes

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen actually this fail even if I set both read & write to `true` - it only works if I move it above to the `users` level - any ideas?

Comment: @DominicTobias Why do you check for existing data? What is your exact usecase here? If we know what behavior you are trying to have we can help you better.

Comment: @AndréKool good point I added it to the top of the Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I initially misunderstood the problem. In your current callback, you are trying to overwrite the entire users level because of how [set](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-set) works.

You would really want to set only the thing that doesn't exist:

```
const userRef = ref.child('users').child(userData.uid);

const userEntry = {
        created: new Date().getTime()
    };

userRef.set(userEntry);
```

Then, I think that your existing rules would work.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, looks like it'll work I'll just verify later/tomorrow cheers

Comment: Well it made sense but it still doesn't work, actually even removing the `.write` rule in the `$uid` and only leaving the `!data.exists()` outer one still doesn't work :/

Comment: @DominicTobias , I didn't originally follow that this was in a callback after you create the user, and that your code looks like it would replace the entire user level? I've updated my answer with how I would try to do it.

Comment: Firebase is a little confusing in that it has a managed user table that's not modifiable, so in order for my Node app to know a user has been added I also need to add an entry to my own user table - so they are in fact two different tables! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @DominicTobias , Ah then I think it is just that your code sets at the users level instead of users/username level, I've updated yet again.. :)

Comment: That was the problem! I didn't know that's how you set child data. Thanks a lot (PS I have to wait 18hrs to award bounty)

Answer (score 1):

I think this a confusing question because creating a user and writing to the database are completely different things. So i will just show how i do it in my app.

1. First step is [creating the user](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html)
2. Next [log the user in](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-login) because creating doesn't automaticly log the user in (I do this in the callback function of create user)
3. Last step is [writing the user data to firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing)

I use the following rule to make sure each user can only write to his own node in firebase ([documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-security.html#section-authorization)):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And one thing to keep in mind is that [set()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-ways-to-save) will replace any existing data at that path. So make sure you use the uid of the user and not the users node.

Finally i want to point out a huge flaw in the rules you posted in your question:

```
".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid"
```

This rule states you can write if there isn't any data yet OR you have the correct uid. The first part of this statement is the problem because **ANYONE** can write to this locaion when there isn't any data. Also because $uid is a [dynamic path](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables) you can add anything there like:

```
"users": {
  "WoWIjustMadeThisUp": {
    "nice": "Some huge value making you go over your limit"
  }
}
```

If you want users to only write an initial value and after that won't be able to edit it just use a [validate rule](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-types) to [check if there is already data at that location](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-data-variables).

Comment: The problem was that I needed to do `ref.child('users').child(userData.uid)` But I think you're right - it's better to prevent public adds to users and just create it when the user first logs in